# Unity3d добавление товара в корзину на WordPress(Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, unity3d, woocommerce

Делаю добавление товара в корзину из приложения на Unity3d по ID-товара в магазин на WordPress(Woocommerce). Передаю из Unity POST запрос, передаю через wwwform,  внутри которого ID-товара. Проблема в том что когда передаю запрос из приложения то товар в корзину не добавляется, хотя ответ в консоль в Unity приложение получаю что ID доходит. Но если передаю post запрос через стороний сервис 
к примеру - http://seriyps.ru/postget/ то товар в корзину добавляется.

Вот код Unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class TestPostConnect : MonoBehaviour {

public string url;  //Переменная для хранения адреса

void Start()
{
    url = "http://********/testWordPress/";
}

public IEnumerator Connect(){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("idcart", 91);
    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
    yield return www;
    if (www.text.Length > 0){
        Debug.Log("Finished uploading data");  
        Debug.Log("Ответ " + www.text);
    }
}
//Создаём метод OnGUI()
void OnGUI()
{
    //Создаём кнопку для произведения подключения
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-25, 200, 20), "Connect"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Connect());
        Application.OpenURL("http://*******/testWordPress/cart/");
        Debug.Log("OnGUI Done!");
    }
}
```

Код php: (функция добавлена в functions.php)

```
    add_action( 'init', 'add_product_new' );
    function add_product_new() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    //$product_id = 91;
      $product_id = $_POST['idcart'];

    $found = false;
    //check if product already in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ){
    $_product = $values['data'];
    if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
      $found = true;
    echo "Product is found!!! ";
  }
  // if product not found, add it
    if ( ! $found )
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    echo "Done2";
  } else {
  // if no products in cart, add it
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id,1);
    echo "Product add: ";
    echo $product_id;
    }
  }
}
```